# How can I "pass" a persistent label in a custom transition animation in iOS8?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios8, transition

I have a custom transition animation between view controllers, and I want a UILabel to be (or appear) the same on both the fromViewController and the toViewController.

I tried the following:

```
toViewController.nameLabel = fromViewController.nameLabel;
```

In the context of the code below but got the following error :

> [UINavigationController nameLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance

What am I doing wrong?

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    // Grab the from and to view controllers from the context
    HC_ExercisePageVC *fromViewController = (HC_ExercisePageVC *)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    HC_TimerVC *toViewController = (HC_TimerVC *)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

    if (self.presenting) {

        fromViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

        [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];

        CGRect startFrame = endFrame;
        startFrame.origin.y += 75;
        toViewController.movingViews.frame = startFrame;

        toViewController.nameLabel = fromViewController.nameLabel;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
            toViewController.movingViews.frame = endFrame;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
        }];
    }
    else {
```

**Update:** Following the suggestion by @Gavin, I replaced the code with:

```
// Grab the from and to view controllers from the context
HC_ExercisePageVC *fromViewController = (HC_ExercisePageVC *)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
UINavigationController *toViewControllerNavigation = (id)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
HC_TimerVC * toViewController = (HC_TimerVC *)toViewControllerNavigation.viewControllers.firstObject;
```

But when I do that I get error:

> -[HC_TimerVC viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I always get hung up on how to handle navcontrollers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `toViewController` is contained within a `UINavigationController`, thus it is returning that as the destination.

So you'll need to grab the `HC_TimerVC` from the navigation controller:

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    // Grab the from and to view controllers from the context
    HC_ExercisePageVC *fromViewController = (HC_ExercisePageVC *)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UINavigationController *toViewControllerNavigation = (id)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    HC_TimerVC * toViewController = toViewControllerNavigation.viewControllers.firstObject;
    ....
```